# How to build a custom FreeBSD release without root privileges?

Tags: freebsd

I am trying to build a custom FreeBSD disk image from source which I could then load with bhyve.

Here's the script I use:

```
export MAKEOBJDIRPREFIX="$HOME/obj"
export CHROOTDIR="$HOME/var"
ncpu="$(sysctl -n hw.ncpu)"

set -e   

cd 
mkdir -p obj
mkdir -p var

svn co http://svn.freebsd.org/base/head ./src
cd src
make -j$ncpu -DNO_CLEAN buildworld buildkernel

cd release
make release -DNODOC -DNOSRC -DNOPORTS
make install DESTDIR=../../var
```

My problem is that `make release` fails.

What is wrong?

---

Here are some parts of the `make release` error message:

> *...*
>
> ```
> .:      user (0, 1001, not modified: Operation not permitted)
> bin:    user (0, 1001, not modified: Operation not permitted)
> boot:   user (0, 1001, not modified: Operation not permitted)
> boot/defaults:
>         user (0, 1001, not modified: Operation not permitted)
> boot/dtb:
>         user (0, 1001, not modified: Operation not permitted)
> boot/firmware:
>         user (0, 1001, not modified: Operation not permitted)
> boot/kernel:
>         user (0, 1001, not modified: Operation not permitted)
> boot/modules:
>         user (0, 1001, not modified: Operation not permitted)
> boot/zfs:
>         user (0, 1001, not modified: Operation not permitted)
> dev:    user (0, 1001, not modified: Operation not permitted)
> etc:    user (0, 1001, not modified: Operation not permitted)
> ```
>
> *...*
>
> ```
> --------------------------------------------------------------
> >>> Distributing everything
> --------------------------------------------------------------
> cd /usr/home/m/src; make -f Makefile.inc1 distribute
> ===> lib (distribute)
> ===> lib/csu (distribute)
> ===> lib/csu/amd64 (distribute)
> cd /usr/home/m/src/lib/csu/amd64;  make install installconfig -DNO_SUBDIR DESTDIR=/usr/home/m/obj/usr/home/m/src/release/dist/base SHARED=copies
> install  -o root -g wheel  -m 444 crt1.o crti.o crtn.o Scrt1.o gcrt1.o /usr/home/m/obj/usr/home/m/src/release/dist/base/usr/lib/
> install: /usr/home/m/obj/usr/home/m/src/release/dist/base/usr/lib/crt1.o: chown/chgrp: Operation not permitted
> *** Error code 71
> ```
>
> *...*

Comment: The operations that are not permitted ar likely changes to ownerships of files.

Comment: @Kusalananda which has to be performed as root, right?

Comment: Yes. Only root may change ownerships of files in the way that `make release` requires.

Comment: @Kusalananda Cool! I'll try that and report back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to pass the `NO_ROOT` environment variable to `make`: see [Makefile.inc1](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/Makefile.inc1?revision=340587&view=markup#l15) for more details.